# Watching Windows file system events, tool, util?

Tags: windows, filesystemwatcher

I am debugging my own file-system driver, and I need to make sure I send
all the correct events, just like NTFS. So I need a way to see all the events
for a volume or directory.

So I came across a PowerShell script on here that uses `New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`, so I use:
https://gist.github.com/lundman/8602b4e2f9b090e8c6abc0a3b98e4ef9

This works quite well, for the usual mkdir/rmdir/rename etc.

But I don't see any events like:
`FILE_ACTION_ADDED_STREAM` or `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_EA`.

Anyone know any good tools/apps/utils for it? or how to expand powershell script? Or some other way..

Comment: Still don't have a great tool, but GH has a WatchDirectory.exe sample that was not too difficult to compile and modify to work with streams and EA events. Ultimately, I would have liked FileSpy.exe (or similar tool) to have events monitoring built in.